# When is the cookie created in Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, session-cookies

I'm learning about Servlet and cookies and I have a missunderstanding. It is possible to create a cookie without using "new Cookie"?

I know that a cookie is created with this statement:

```
Cookie ck = new Cookie("username",name);
```

And the below statement is used to send the cookie at the client browser:

```
response.addCookie(ck);
```

But I have found an app and it doesn't have the statement above and it create a cookie in my browser. Is the cookie created when I create a new session if I don't use "new Cookie" in my code?

This is the code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="Validate">
  User: <input type="text" name="user" /><br/>
  Password: <input type="password" name="pass" ><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Validate.java

```
package servlet.httpses;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Validate
 */
@WebServlet("/Validate")
public class Validate extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Validate() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        String name = request.getParameter("user");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

        if(pass.equals("1234")) {

            //creating a session
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();

            session.setAttribute("user", name);

            response.sendRedirect("Welcome");
        }
    }
}
```

Welcome.java

```
package servlet.httpses;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Welcome
 */
@WebServlet("/Welcome")
public class Welcome extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Welcome() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        String user = (String) session.getAttribute("user");

        out.println("Hello " + user);

        out.println("<br>Session ID in Request is from a Cookie: " 
        + request.isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie());

        out.println("<br> Session ID: " + session.getId());
        out.println("<br> Creation Time: " + new Date(session.getCreationTime()));
        out.println("<br>Last Accessed Time: " + new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime()));
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

When is the cookie created in this case? It is possible to create a cookie without using "new cookie"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, sessions are tracked using a cookie, as explained in the specifications: https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr369/index.html. It's created when a session is created.

Comment: cookies can be created with javascript too

Answer (score -1):

You can create cookies in two ways.

1. Create a cookie on server and send that to client
2. Create a cookie on client side

When you are using new Cookie java creates a cookie object and sends to the client side and client saves the cookie.

On the other hand you can create cookie with the help of JavaScript using some data.